# How to inspect all list elements and remove one if meets condition without using a loop or iterators

Tags: c++, list, loops, iterator

what I am trying to accomplish is pretty much what it says in the title. I currently have a program which is supposed to read from a list of assignments and "prune" (remove) the bad assignments based on the boolean condition and function "IsGood". I am able to read the list and write back to an output file. My function that checks if the assignment is good or not works correctly. How do you check the entire list and remove the bad element without using iterators or a loop? Thank you in advance.

```
        Functions I am using:

std::string m_Name;
std::list<Assignment> m_Assignments;


 bool IsGood() const
{
    return m_IsGood;
}

void IsGood(bool isGood)
{
    m_IsGood = isGood;
}

void Prune()
{

}
```

What I believe I'm supposed to use.

```
    m_Assignments.erase(std::remove(m_Assignments.begin(),
    m_Assignments.end(),IsGood()), m_Assignments.end())
```

but i am getting a scope error when trying to use the IsGood function

Comment: *"without using iterators or a loop"*: `m_Assignments.begin()` is an iterator, and under the hood `erase`/`remove` loops.

Answer (score 1):

You should use `remove_if` with correct predicate, it should be:

```
m_Assignments.remove_if([](const Assignment& assignment){ return !assignment.IsGood();}));
```

Comment: ok thanks that makes sense but is there a way to do it with c++11? getting the error " use of 'auto' in lambda parameter declaration only available with -stdc++14..."

Comment: There is also a [`std::list::remove_if`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list/remove) member function that does the remove/erase in a single pass.

Comment: @Blastfurnace: Indeed, replaced.

Comment: @Mark.B: I replaced `auto` by real type.